# show query data grouped horizontally

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by

I have a table where I store transfers. each transfer has a date , and a number of `movil`. I need to make a monthly statistics, the number of transfers per day per `movil`.
The query works great, but the problem is that I need to show each day in a column, and each `movil` in a row.
My idea was to keep all result in a multidimensional array. But it is very slow then to search for values ​​.

This is the transfers table:

```
id  fecha      movil
1   01/08/2016  A
2   01/08/2016  A
3   01/08/2016  B
4   02/08/2016  A
5   02/08/2016  B
6   02/08/2016  B
7   02/08/2016  C
8   02/08/2016  A
9   03/08/2016  A
10  03/08/2016  B
```

This is my query:

```
select DAY(fecha),movil, count(id)
from traslados
where YEAR(fecha) = '2016' and MONTH(fecha) = '07' and movil is not null 
group by DAY(fecha),movil
```

Now, I have to show the results in a table with the following format:

```
movil/fecha  1  2   3
A            2  1   1   
B            1  2   1   
C            0  1   0
```

Is there a way I can do this in the query, or in php code?

ADDED

this is how the result of my query looks:

```
DAY(FECHA)  MOVIL   COUNT
1              A    2
1              B    1
2              A    2
2              B    2
2              C    1
3              A    1
3              A    1
```

It has all the data I want, but not the format.

This was my attempt:

```
<?
    $maxDias  = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, '07', '2016');
    $cons = "select DAY(fecha) as dia,movil, count(idTraslado) as cantidad
        from traslados
        where YEAR(fecha) = '2016' and MONTH(fecha) = '07' and movil is not null 
        and (idObraSocial = 20 or idObraSocial = 5)
        group by DAY(fecha),movil";
    $result = mysql_query($cons, $conexion);
    $filas = mysql_affected_rows();


    $array = array();
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $array[] = $data;
    }

    print_r($array);


    $consMoviles = "select DISTINCT movil from traslados
    where YEAR(fecha) = '2016' and MONTH(fecha) = '07' and movil is not null 
    and (idObraSocial = 20 or idObraSocial = 5)
    order by movil";
    $resultMoviles = mysql_query($consMoviles, $conexion);
    $cantMoviles = mysql_affected_rows();
    ?>
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="success">

            <th>
                Movil/Día
            </th>
            <?for ($i = 1; $i < $maxDias; $i++) {?>
                <th>
                    <?echo $i;?>
                </th>
            <?}?>
        </tr>



    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <? while ($rowMovil = mysql_fetch_array($resultMoviles, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <?=$rowMovil["movil"];?>
            </th>
            <?for ($i = 1; $i < $maxDias; $i++) {?>
                <th>
                    HERE SHOW DATA
                </th>
            <?}?>
        </tr>
        <?}?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What's the result of the query?  Does it have the data you expect?  What attempt have you made to display it?

Comment: mysql_fetch_array might be your friend here, although I guess you want the full code...

Comment: i added data to the question.

Comment: can i search a value in my array, having the day and the movil, without iteration ? beacuse i have about 30 moviles and 31 days of the month, it will turn ver slow !!!